# Updating UI controls in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have initialized and rendered a Google Maps object with my own UI-settings. Now when a user interacts I want to change what and where to display some of the controls. For instance I try to do this ->

```
map.mapTypeControl = true;
map.mapTypeControlOptions = {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
                        position: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.RIGHT_CENTER
                    };
```

where `map` is my Google Maps object, but the map doesn't render it. What do I need to do to make my google Maps object update it's settings?

I've used this page as reference, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls, but can't figure it out.

A general answer on how to update these type of settings is most welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mistake from me. Should have done ->

```
map.setOptions({
    mapTypeControlOptions: { 
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT, 
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER }
});
```